# TypeScript imports vs. ES6 object destructuring

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.0, object-destructuring

With TS imports, I believe I can do this:

```
import {foo as bar} from 'foo';
```

with ES6 object destructuring in JS or TypeScript - is there a way to rename an "imported value" in the same way?

For example,

```
const {longVarName as lvn} = x.bar;
```

Comment: `const {longVarName:lvn} = x.bar;`? would result in a const called lvn having the value of x.bar.longVarName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the solution suggested by *Jaromanda X*:

```
const {longVarName: lvn} = x.bar;
```

In fact, you can do more than that:

Multiple variables

```
var {p: foo, q: bar} = o;
```

Default values:

```
var {a = 10, b = 5} = {a: 3};
```

Nested objects:

```
const x = {a: {b: {c: 10}}};
const {a: {b: {c: ten}}} = x;
// ten === 10
```

For more info, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: this ES6 right? not typescript?

Comment: Yes, this is ES6, correct.

Comment: I can confirm it works with TypeScript as well, which makes sense since TS follows ES6 somewhat closely.